# In React Native, how can I use values that I saved in a local storage with AsyncStorage for rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, storage, asyncstorage

I just want to use the demo object 'person' in JSX or globally, which was saved in the local storage with AsyncStorage.

Here are codes that I tried so far.
It just throw an error saying Can't find the valuable '''person'''

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";



const Home = () => {
  const Jhon = { id: 1, age: 30 };
  const demo = async () => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("person", JSON.stringify(Jhon));
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("person");
      const person = JSON.parse(value);
      console.log(person);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  demo();

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      //Here, I want to use this object person to show it.
      <Text style={styles.text}>{person}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    flex: 1,
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 50,
  },
});

export default Home;
```

I think I know that in oreder to use the object outside that function, I need to use `return` the value and store it to a valuable such as const X and then comsume it, but after trying to play around with it, I just messed up and am now completely stuck.

How would you do it? It'd be nice if you could fix my codes to make it work.
Thank you in advance.

My real goal is to be able to save and use state values so that even if the user closes my app, they can start/contenu from　where they left off

Answer (score 0):

You should call this `demo` function in `useEffect` so that means you should call these async stuff inside the lifecycle.

Here is an example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    await demo();
  })();
}, []);
```

Comment: Sorry, exactly where should I put the async stuff?

Comment: I think you should read lifecycles on react native and how to use them with useEffect. 

https://www.codemzy.com/blog/how-to-use-react-useeffect-like-componentdidmount

Here is a good article for this. 


You should put the async stuff into the lifecycle, so you make sure that async stuff will be called in time, not before the dom or component is created/called.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation! i'm going to give it a read!